# Syntax error in bit packing a structure in C after switching compiler and IDE

Tags: c, gcc, struct, bit-packing

Okay, what am I missing....

I wrote the code originally on an IAR IDE/compiler for use on an ARM microprocessor and it worked fine.

We are now switching to a different controller with a Tricore microprocessor and are now using code::blocks IDE with GNU GCC compiler for TriCore v3.4.6.

When building I am getting the errors with the below two structures (related enums given for reference):

```
01| typedef enum equip_states_t {
02|   stopped = 0,
03|   starting = 1,
04|   running = 2,
05|   paused = 3,
06|   stopping = 4
07| }equip_states_t;
08| 
09| typedef enum info_level_t{
10|   clear = 0,
11|   alert = 1,
12|   warning = 2,
13|   error = 3
14| } info_level_t;
15| 
16| typedef struct d2101_equip_states_t {
17|   equip_states_t        AIR_COMP_state:4; //Error starts here
18|   pause_states_t        auto_pause_state:4;
19|   fullness_states_t     BE_fullness:4;
20|   equip_states_t        BE_state:4;
21|   fullness_states_t     BIN_fullness:4;
22|   bin_states_t          BIN_state:4;
23|   bin_states_t          BYPASS_state:4;
24|   control_modes_t       control_mode:4;
25|   equip_states_t        DC_state:4;
26|   source_dest_t         DIV_auto_pause:4;
27|   source_dest_t         DIV_position:4;
28|   equip_states_t        HYDR_state:4;
29|   equip_states_t        QL_state:4;
30|   fullness_states_t     TC_fullness:4;
31|   equip_states_t        TC_state:4;
32|   equip_states_t        TUC_state:4;
33| } d2101_equip_states_t;
34| 
35| typedef struct info_message_t {
36|   uint16_t              ID;  //Error starts here
37|   info_level_t          status:8;
38|   uint8_t               not_used;
39|   uint32_t              time_stamp:32;
40| } info_message_t;
```

The errors are:

```
[18] error: [11705] syntax error before "pause_states_t"
[18] warning: [11407] no semicolon at end of struct or union
[19] error: [11707] syntax error before ':' token
[20] error: [11707] syntax error before ':' token
[21] error: [11707] syntax error before ':' token
[24] error: [11707] syntax error before ':' token
[25] error: [11707] syntax error before ':' token
[26] error: [11707] syntax error before ':' token
[27] error: [11707] syntax error before ':' token
[28] error: [11707] syntax error before ':' token
[29] error: [11707] syntax error before ':' token
[30] error: [11707] syntax error before ':' token
[31] error: [11707] syntax error before ':' token
[32] error: [11707] syntax error before ':' token
[33] warning: [13263] type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'd2101_equip_states_t'
[33] warning: [10516] data definition has no type or storage class
[37] error: [11705] syntax error before "info_level_t"
[37] warning: [11407] no semicolon at end of struct or union
[39] error: [11707] syntax error before ':' token
[40] warning: [13263] type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'info_message_t'
[40] warning: [10516] data definition has no type or storage class
```

**HOWEVER...**
In many, many other instances, including some before and after in the same file, I use the same syntax with no errors and hence my confusion on what is going wrong.  E.G.

```
typedef struct rmt2001_feedback_to_remote_t{
  uint8_t               screen_number;
  bool                  fault_present:1;
  switch_states_t       DC:1;
  switch_states_t       air:1;
  switch_states_t       HYDR:1;
  switch_states_t       TUC:1;
  switch_states_t       BE:1;
  switch_states_t       TC:1;
  switch_states_t       green_backlight:1;
  source_dest_t         dest:3;
  equip_states_t        status:3;
  switch_states_t       red_backlight:1;
  switch_states_t       blue_backlight:1;
  uint8_t               gate_percent;
  uint8_t               bin_percent;
  uint8_t               BE_amps_msb;
  uint8_t               BE_amps_lsb;
  uint8_t               not_used;
} rmt2001_feedback_to_remote_t;

typedef struct IO_view_t{
  master_or_slave_t     master_or_slave:1;
  uint8_t               exponent:3;
  uint8_t               controller_id:4;
  uint8_t               io_id:6;
  A_of_D_t              A_or_D:1;
  I_or_O_t              I_or_O:1;
  uint16_t              raw;
  int16_t               value;
} IO_view_t;
```

If I remember correctly what I have read elsewhere on this site is that structure bit packing isn't very consistent between compilers as it's not clearly/strictly defined by c standard.  I also read that using bitwise operations with masks and offsets is a more cross platform friendly way of doing bit packing and failing anything else I can do that.... But I want to know why this doesn't work in only these two instances and I am hoping there is some simple little thing that will save me from having to do this.

Thank you everyone for your time in reading this.

Comment: Probably they don't allow enum-based bit-fields, simple as that. You could try to toss them out and use `uint32_t` or `uint8_t`. Also make sure that you compile with `-std=c11`.

Comment: Are you using the same compiler flags?  Which ones?

Comment: To build on @Lundin's comment, when I compile with gcc (with `-std=c99` or `-std=c11`) with pedantic warnings, I get `warning: type of bit-field '<name of field>' is a GCC extension` for all of the bitfields of enum types.

Comment: Thank you @Lundin and @christian-gibbons for your quick responses, but it turns out it was the compiler treating `pause_states_t` and `info_level_t` as blanks because their type def hadn't been read yet.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**And the answer is...** it has to do with the order the structure data types typedefs were being read between the two compilers and/or because of minor structural changes to the program because of the different controller.

If I move the typedef of `pause_states_t` and `info_level_t` to another file that is definitely read before this file, the error goes away.

It seems like instead of getting some sort of "unrecognized symbol" or "unrecognized data type" error, it treats it as if is blank and this is what triggers the errors.

This is consistent with some other errors I'm getting now where the compiler is encountering customer data types before the typedef is read.